# How can we use pivot in sql for this scenario?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

TABLE 1

```
CODE      ID
A         1d
B         2f
C         1d
B         3r
C         2f
A         3r
D         8r
```

where CODE and ID are nonunique columns.

I want to transform it to

Expected query result :

```
A     B     C
1d   null  1d
null 2f    2f
3r   3r    null
```

Where A, B and C which were records in column 'CODE' and I want to transform them into columns,
 and wherever we don't have adjacent ID for the code I want it to be null.

I tried something like

```
SELECT *
from TABLE 1
pivot (coalesce (id, 'null')  for CODE in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

which is totally wrong

It will be a great help if someone can help.

Sorry for bad formatting this is my 1st question.

Comment: I see no relationships between your source data and desired results.  Either fix the data or provide an explanation.

Comment: show your expected output ..

Comment: Where's column `D`? Where are those nulls coming from?

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't want column D even though it is in rows.

Comment: @KhairulAlam query result is my expected output

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited question with explanation.

Comment: @KhairulAlam . . . Where does A/3r go?  Where does A/2r come from?  Where does C/2f go?

Comment: how can it be a expected output ?

Comment: Pivot function can be used to transform raw data into the column and which is what I want to do as a result.

Answer (score 2):

This query will show the result you want:

```
select
  max(case when t.code = 'A' then t.id end) as a,
  max(case when t.code = 'B' then t.id end) as b,
  max(case when t.code = 'C' then t.id end) as c
from (select distinct id from table1 where code in ('A', 'B', 'C')) d
join table1 t on t.id = d.id
group by d.id
order by d.id
```

Result:

```
A       B       C      
------  ------  ------
1d      <null>  1d     
<null>  2f      2f     
3r      3r      <null>
```

For the record, here's the data script I used to test it:

```
create table table1 (code varchar2(9), id varchar2(5));

insert into table1 (code, id) values ('A', '1d');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('B', '2f');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('C', '1d');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('B', '3r');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('C', '2f');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('A', '3r');
insert into table1 (code, id) values ('D', '8r');
```

Comment: It indeed solves the problem but as I mentioned I want it with pivot function.
Is there a way we can solve it with pivot ?
And really thanks for solution. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
with data (CODE , ID) as (
select 'A','1d' from dual union all 
select 'B','2f' from dual union all 
select 'C','1d' from dual union all 
select 'B','3r' from dual union all 
select 'C','2f' from dual union all 
select 'A','3r' from dual union all 
select 'D','8r' from dual
)
select A,B,C from (
  select code, id, substr(id,1,1) rn 
  from data
  where code in ('A', 'B', 'C')
)
pivot (max(id) for code in('A' as A, 'B' as B, 'C' as C))
order by rn;

A  B  C 
-- -- --
1d    1d
   2f 2f
3r 3r
```